Why was the Emperor silent here?
The Emperor failed to act or speak out after the surprise Harkonnen attack
on Arrakis, which destroyed the Atreides family. Princess Irulan finds her
father, the Emperor's, inaction difficult to accept, as she knows he loved
Duke Leto Atreides like a son.
Why was the Emperor silent here?

Because he did it. It's the same as Brandon (and Scholz) being silent after the destruction of 3 pipes of NordStream, basically implementing the final deindustrialization of Germany, if I may say so.

He's complicit in the attack.

Behind closed doors the Emperor was livid at the actions of the Baron Harkonnen in killing the Duke. He wanted him out of office and into exile (possibly to return as a House Minor at some point?) but he didn't want him dead.
In public, and that includes in front of his daughter who at this point is unaware that Imperial troops were secretly used to attack Arrakis, he says nothing. As far as the Imperial Council are concerned, the Emperor is holding himself aloof from a legally valid spat between two houses. He can't be seen to be taking sides.

KANLY: formal feud or vendetta under the rules of the Great Convention carried on according to the strictest limitations. (See Judge of the Change.) Originally the rules were designed to protect innocent bystanders.
Dune

There's no point protesting the victor when that could lead to his treachery being exposed. Nothing, as they say, strengthens authority so much as silence.


Behind closed doors the Emperor was livid at the actions of the Baron Harkonnen in killing the Duke

Could you remind me where this is stated? It's been a while since I read the book, but I don't remember this. I always assumed the Emperor wanted Leto dead; it's not like the Emperor to misunderstand what kind of beasts the Harkonnen are and what they would do, given the chance...

@AndresF. - "When my father, the Padishah Emperor, heard of Duke Leto’s death and the manner of it, he went into such a rage as we had never before seen. He blamed my mother and the compact forced on him to place a Bene Gesserit on the throne. He blamed the Guild and the evil old Baron. He blamed everyone in sight, not excepting even me, for he said I was a witch like all the others. And when I sought to comfort him, saying it was done according to an older law of self-preservation to which even the most ancient rulers gave allegiance, 1/2

he sneered at me and asked if I thought him a weakling. I saw then that he had been aroused to this passion not by concern over the dead Duke but by what that death implied for all royalty. As I look back on it, I think there may have been some prescience in my father, too, for it is certain that his line and Muad’Dib’s shared common ancestry. - “In My Father’s House,” by the Princess Irulan"

@AndresF. - The Emperor was very keen for the Duke to just be deposed. He absolutely didn't want him dead, and even went so far as commanding the Baron to ensure that it didn't happen. The Baron has to go through contortions to ensure that when he's asked about the Duke's death, he can claim with absolute truth that he didn't command it to happen.

nice! Pretty convincing quotes, it seems you are right.

@AndresF. - There is, as always, no need to say "Valorum is right", since that's a tautology.
